# Mapping error with ChildBrowser and PhoneGap 1.5.0 (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

When I try to call:

window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage

I get this error in the console window:

2012-03-13 16:14:58.036 CordovaHybridDemo[874:707] ERROR: Plugin 'ChildBrowserCommand' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.

I added an entry in Cordova.plist with a key of ChildBrowserCommand and a value of ChildBrowserCommand. That worked in PhoneGap 1.4.1 but has that changed for Cordova?

Comment: Having the same problem with cordova 1.6.1; did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova changing their plugin architecture. Including keywords and files, classes.

Check your ChildBrowserCommand.h file

```
@interface ChildBrowserCommand : CDVPlugin <ChildBrowserDelegate>
```

For this. If it is not CDVPlugin you have not updated your plugin files successfully. Analogy might be apply for Android.

Check the updated js file for the plugin also.

```
var cordovaRef = window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova; // old to new fallbacks
```

Here they make plugins usable for new cordova.

Refer this plugin upgration guide by Cordova
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/README.md

Answer (score 0):

[The answer is right here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser), [in the picture](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/raw/master/iOS/ChildBrowser/Cordova.plist.png).  It doesn't mention it in the text, but this key/value pair has to be nested under Plugins.

I struggled with this for a while before I noticed I'd messed it up.  I blame the Xcode UI: if you click the + on Plugins while it's closed, it just creates a sibling, not a child.  Also my first mistake was to put this keypair in the wrong plist file entirely :P.